# Whether the `odd-even check` only can check the data correctness within limits?

Tags: math, bit, parity

> The length of DES arithmetic Secret Key is 64 bit, the valid secret key length is 56, the other 8 bit use as `odd-even check`.

I have a question, whether the `odd-even check` only can check the data correctness within limits?

such as the quote, I use below image to explain my thought:

[image]

the first line, the `odd check` value is `0`, if I switch the `row 2` and `row 3`, the `odd check` value still is the `0`, so the `odd-even check` can not check this issue.

so the `odd-even check` can only check the count of `1` and `0`, but can not decide the data whether is correct, right?

Comment: There is always a limit, as shown by Claude Shannon back in the 40s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The odd-even check catches a change in *one* bit, but swapping a `1` and a `0` involves changing *two* bits. There are methods that can catch a change of two bits, but they require more than one check bit.